# How to add column to show WEEKNUM as "start date - end date"?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to create an additional column which shows something like the below function however instead show something like (12/29/2020 - 1/4/2020).

*weekinmonth = 1 + WEEKNUM ('Query'[Creation Date] )-WEEKNUM( STARTOFMONTH ('Query'[Creation Date]))*

- this returns values 1 - 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your new column, using the example of the date 29/07/2020, you do need to use the weekday number then work out the start and end using it

[image]

```
Start & End of Week = 
VAR StartWeek = FORMAT((Table1[Date] - WEEKDAY(Table1[Date], 1) + 1), "MM/DD/YYYY")
VAR EndWeek = FORMAT((Table1[Date] - WEEKDAY(Table1[Date], 1 ) + 7), "MM/DD/YYYY")
RETURN 
StartWeek & " - " & EndWeek
```

In your example you listed 12/29/2020 as the start of the week, which is a Tuesday, update the + 1 and +7 to get the right offset.

If you want, you can use the M function Date.StartOfWeek, and Date.EndOfWeek to to create the column before it gets to the data model.